# Looping through pages of search result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Reuters image captions on certain pictures. I have searched with my parameters and have a search result with 182 pages. The 'PN=X' part at the end of the links are the page numbers. I have built a for loop to loop through the pages and scrape all captions:

```
pages = ['https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN=1', 
'https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN=2', 
'https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN=3',
'https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN=4', ...]

complete_captions = []
for link in pages:
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    for element in soup.find_all(id=re.compile("CaptionLong_Lbl")):
        if not element.text.endswith('...'):
            complete_captions.append(element.text)
```

The code runs, but it returns the same captions regardless of the page it is given. It just repeats the same 47 results over and over again. But when I enter the pages into my browser, they are different from each other. So it should give different results. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: are you sure the links are correct? when I open some of the links [link1](https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN=1), it redirects to the same page with 404 status and that could be the reason for the same captions.

Comment: Weird, the links work fine for me. Just tried it again, and even in different browsers the links work. I guess that could mean there is some issues with the links

Comment: Could you comment a specific link that works for you in the comments that I could try?

Comment: can you add re expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this website, to get different results for each page is more complicated than just adding a page number to the URL and using `requests.get()`.

A simpler approach in this case would be to use selenium, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
                             
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
complete_captions = []

for page_number in range(1, 5):
    print(f"Page {page_number}")
    
    url = f'https://pictures.reuters.com/CS.aspx?VP3=SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688#/SearchResult&VBID=2C0BXZS52QWLHI&SMLS=1&RW=1920&RH=688&PN={page_number}'
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    for element in soup.find_all(id=re.compile("CaptionLong_Lbl")):
        if not element.text.endswith('...'):
            complete_captions.append(element.text)
            #print(element.text)
            
browser.quit()
```

Obviously, a different browser can be used.